# NSFetchedResultsController update when relationship updates?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Imagine I have a data model that has 2 entities:  Movie and Genre.

A Movie can belong to many Genres, as a Genre can have many Movies.

Now.  I want to have a NSFetchedResultsController that observes the Genre entity (using the genre's name as a sectionNameKeyPath)

Say I import some data, and a Genre gets a Movie added to it during the import.

The question is:  Will the NSFetchedResultsController delegate (controllerWillChangeContent: , etc.) methods be called (because the Genre.movies.count has changed)?

If not, how can I make that happen?  In Swift?

(Yes I know there are other questions like this out there, but none seem to be succinct or have an official answer)

(May be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859421/force-nsfetchedresultscontroller-update-when-association-count-changes):)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will update if the relationship on the entity updates.  It will not update if a property in `Movie` changes even if the predicate is set to monitor that.

Answer (score 0):

YES, on import of a `Movie` to a `Genre`, `controllerWillChangeContent:` of the `FetchedResultsController` observing `Genre` will be invoked.